# ga is undefined when using Tag Manager to manage Analytics scripts

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to send events with custom script managed in Tag Manager.
However, it seems that ga is undefined when using Tag Manager to manage Google Analytics script.

So, I cannot use `ga('send',...)`. And since I've already got all the code ready to send my data to Google Analytics I wouldn't like to create another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to edit Google Analytics settings in Tag Manager.

You need to select from Advanced Configuration > Tracker Name and leave it empty.